# What is the symbolism of the changes of the bride's attire in Ready or Not?

Tags: analysis, ready-or-not

In the 2019 film, Ready or Not, we meet the bride Grace.

> She goes from being adorned as the typical beautiful bride to tearing the bottom of her dress off, having her sleeve ripped off, having a gate iron tear a gash in the back of her dress, while changing from heels to Converse Chucks.  Oh, also she gets covered in blood, from head to toe.

What is the symbolism here regarding her appearance, specifically with her choices to change it?

Comment: What makes you believe there's supposed to be any symbolic meaning to it?

Comment: Having seen enough cinema in my 50 years, and having taken film classes, I know symbolism when I see it.  I just can't identify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines would've given you the answer to this.

[Source 1](https://www.syfy.com/syfy-wire/weaponizing-the-wedding-dress-and-transforming-the-final-girl-in-ready-or-not):

> The white of a wedding gown traditionally symbolizes purity.

and

> The image of a bride on her wedding day doesn't typically conjure up
> the notion of battle-ready attire; it isn’t common for a gown to
> become a weapon or a form of protection. In Ready or Not, Grace’s
> ensemble quickly transforms from a demure vision into a fierce frock
> that symbolizes survival. She might look like “a little blonde twig,”
> but this bride isn’t going down without a fight.

[Source 2](https://www.insider.com/how-transforming-wedding-dress-was-designed-for-ready-or-not-2019-8#:%7E:text=For%20%22Ready%20or%20Not%2C%22,worn%20by%20her%20stunt%20double.):

> For "Ready or Not," the dress was supposed to symbolize Grace's
> journey from her happy wedding day to the brutal, bloody
> ending...Well, the dress evolves throughout the film and goes through
> a series of five stages based on the various things that happen to
> her...So, the dress isn't just a visual representation of her
> character; it's also functional.

[Source 3](https://www.dazeddigital.com/fashion/article/46219/1/ready-or-not-horror-comedy-movie-samara-weaving-final-girl-avery-plewes-costumes):

> ...rips off the bottom of her gown to gain some mobility, marking a
> shift in tone both in her attitude and the film itself. As Ready or
> Not enters its second chapter, Grace is no longer weeping in fear or
> tripping over the dress that symbolises the moment she was handed over
> to her new, bloodthirsty family – she is able to run, climb, and jump
> as she fights tooth and nail for her life. “Ripping the dress is an
> important character point as it shows, okay, this is survival now. Not
> so much a bride anymore.”